# Embed Internet Explorer window inside Inno Setup (web browser control)

Tags: browser, dll, installation, embed, inno-setup

I want to show some web page *INSIDE* Inno Setup installer page, how can it be embedded? 
I was thinking of using cwebpage.dll ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla ), but I have no idea how to use this dll with the means of Inno Setup scripting. If there are some other means, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible directly in InnoSetup, you can use only components listed in the [`Classes Reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm). However you can embed your setup with the custom form from a library e.g. [`this way`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8586403/960757).

I've created an example of such library with a sample InnoSetup script. This project is [`hosted here`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/#svn/trunk).

Comment: That is not I want, I don't need replacement of the Inno Setup form, I need embedded web browser window (without any buttons, just window of web page) in Inno Setup page (e.g. installation progress).

Comment: That's what is not possible. The only way is to show your own form. Custom pages in InnoSetup supports only those components (classes) listed in the [`classes reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm).

Comment: And if we get handle of some page element and draw browser window in it? Is there a way to get handle of Inno Setup form elements?

Comment: But how would you instantiate the web browser ? I think it's possible (not sure) to get handle of each page but what would you do with it. You would open e.g. IE and `SetParent` of it to the setup page ? Even if this would be possible I strongly suggest to don't do that.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I was going to use cwebpage.dll , so having the handle I can use it for creating new browser window with the help of newly created dll (like a wrapper for cwebpage.dll)

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that. You can try it, but I would personally prefer the custom form from *.dll, not the way of embedding wizard pages. The handle of some wizard page you can reach like this way `WizardForm.WelcomePage.Handle` in `[code]` section of your script.

Answer (score 0):

"shellexec" an .html file or web link.  That's all there is to it :)

Comment: I need showing the browser window INSIDE installer page, not launching a link.